# I can't install Open CV

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, conv-neural-network

I am trying to install Open CV for this tutorial...
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hqf__FlRlzg&list=WL&index=4&t=2494s
I have installed it and when I type pip list in the terminal it shows that I have installed it

```
pip list
Package                                Version   
-------------------------------------- ----------
absl-py                                0.8.1     
alabaster                              0.7.12    
anaconda-client                        1.7.2     
anaconda-navigator                     1.9.7     
anaconda-project                       0.8.3     
appnope                                0.1.0     
appscript                              1.0.1     
asn1crypto                             0.24.0    
astor                                  0.8.0     
astroid                                2.2.5     
astropy                                3.2.1     
atomicwrites                           1.3.0     
attrs                                  19.1.0    
Babel                                  2.7.0     
backcall                               0.1.0     
backports.functools-lru-cache          1.5       
backports.os                           0.1.1     
backports.shutil-get-terminal-size     1.0.0     
backports.tempfile                     1.0       
backports.weakref                      1.0.post1 
beautifulsoup4                         4.7.1     
bitarray                               0.9.3     
bkcharts                               0.2       
bleach                                 3.1.0     
bokeh                                  1.2.0     
boto                                   2.49.0    
Bottleneck                             1.2.1     
certifi                                2019.11.28
cffi                                   1.12.3    
chardet                                3.0.4     
Click                                  7.0       
cloudpickle                            1.2.1     
clyent                                 1.2.2     
colorama                               0.4.1     
conda                                  4.8.0     
conda-build                            3.18.8    
conda-package-handling                 1.3.11    
conda-verify                           3.4.2     
contextlib2                            0.5.5     
cryptography                           2.7       
cycler                                 0.10.0    
Cython                                 0.29.12   
cytoolz                                0.10.0    
dask                                   2.1.0     
decorator                              4.4.0     
defusedxml                             0.6.0     
distributed                            2.1.0     
docutils                               0.14      
entrypoints                            0.3       
et-xmlfile                             1.0.1     
fastcache                              1.1.0     
filelock                               3.0.12    
Flask                                  1.1.1     
future                                 0.17.1    
gast                                   0.3.2     
gevent                                 1.4.0     
glob2                                  0.7       
gmpy2                                  2.0.8     
greenlet                               0.4.15    
grpcio                                 1.16.1    
h5py                                   2.9.0     
heapdict                               1.0.0     
html5lib                               1.0.1     
idna                                   2.8       
imageio                                2.5.0     
imagesize                              1.1.0     
importlib-metadata                     0.17      
ipykernel                              5.1.1     
ipython                                7.6.1     
ipython-genutils                       0.2.0     
ipywidgets                             7.5.0     
isort                                  4.3.21    
itsdangerous                           1.1.0     
jdcal                                  1.4.1     
jedi                                   0.13.3    
Jinja2                                 2.10.1    
joblib                                 0.13.2    
json5                                  0.8.4     
jsonschema                             3.0.1     
jupyter                                1.0.0     
jupyter-client                         5.3.1     
jupyter-console                        6.0.0     
jupyter-core                           4.5.0     
jupyterlab                             1.0.2     
jupyterlab-server                      1.0.0     
Keras-Applications                     1.0.8     
Keras-Preprocessing                    1.1.0     
keyring                                18.0.0    
kiwisolver                             1.1.0     
lazy-object-proxy                      1.4.1     
libarchive-c                           2.8       
lief                                   0.9.0     
llvmlite                               0.29.0    
locket                                 0.2.0     
lxml                                   4.3.4     
Markdown                               3.1.1     
MarkupSafe                             1.1.1     
matplotlib                             3.1.0     
mccabe                                 0.6.1     
mistune                                0.8.4     
mkl-fft                                1.0.12    
mkl-random                             1.0.2     
mkl-service                            2.0.2     
mock                                   3.0.5     
more-itertools                         7.0.0     
MouseInfo                              0.1.2     
mpmath                                 1.1.0     
msgpack                                0.6.1     
multipledispatch                       0.6.0     
navigator-updater                      0.2.1     
nbconvert                              5.5.0     
nbformat                               4.4.0     
networkx                               2.3       
nltk                                   3.4.4     
nose                                   1.3.7     
notebook                               6.0.0     
numba                                  0.44.1    
numexpr                                2.6.9     
numpy                                  1.16.4    
numpydoc                               0.9.1     
olefile                                0.46      
opencv-python                          4.1.2.30  
openpyxl                               2.6.2     
packaging                              19.0      
pandas                                 0.24.2    
pandocfilters                          1.4.2     
parso                                  0.5.0     
partd                                  1.0.0     
path.py                                12.0.1    
pathlib2                               2.3.4     
patsy                                  0.5.1     
pep8                                   1.7.1     
pexpect                                4.7.0     
pickleshare                            0.7.5     
Pillow                                 6.1.0     
pip                                    19.3.1    
pkginfo                                1.5.0.1   
pluggy                                 0.12.0    
ply                                    3.11      
prometheus-client                      0.7.1     
prompt-toolkit                         2.0.9     
protobuf                               3.11.2    
psutil                                 5.6.3     
ptyprocess                             0.6.0     
py                                     1.8.0     
PyAutoGUI                              0.9.48    
pycodestyle                            2.5.0     
pycosat                                0.6.3     
pycparser                              2.19      
pycrypto                               2.6.1     
pycurl                                 7.43.0.3  
pyflakes                               2.1.1     
pygame                                 1.9.6     
PyGetWindow                            0.0.8     
Pygments                               2.4.2     
pylint                                 2.3.1     
PyMsgBox                               1.0.7     
pyobjc                                 6.1       
pyobjc-core                            6.1       
pyobjc-framework-Accounts              6.1       
pyobjc-framework-AddressBook           6.1       
pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptKit        6.1       
pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptObjC       6.1       
pyobjc-framework-ApplicationServices   6.1       
pyobjc-framework-Automator             6.1       
pyobjc-framework-AVFoundation          6.1       
pyobjc-framework-AVKit                 6.1       
pyobjc-framework-CalendarStore         6.1       
pyobjc-framework-CFNetwork             6.1       
pyobjc-framework-CloudKit              6.1       
pyobjc-framework-Cocoa                 6.1       
pyobjc-framework-Collaboration         6.1       
pyobjc-framework-CoreAudio             6.1       
pyobjc-framework-CoreAudioKit          6.1       
pyobjc-framework-CoreBluetooth         6.1       
pyobjc-framework-CoreData              6.1       
pyobjc-framework-CoreLocation          6.1       
pyobjc-framework-CoreMedia             6.1       
pyobjc-framework-CoreMediaIO           6.1       
pyobjc-framework-CoreServices          6.1       
pyobjc-framework-CoreText              6.1       
pyobjc-framework-CoreWLAN              6.1       
pyobjc-framework-CryptoTokenKit        6.1       
pyobjc-framework-DictionaryServices    6.1       
pyobjc-framework-DiscRecording         6.1       
pyobjc-framework-DiscRecordingUI       6.1       
pyobjc-framework-DiskArbitration       6.1       
pyobjc-framework-DVDPlayback           6.1       
pyobjc-framework-EventKit              6.1       
pyobjc-framework-ExceptionHandling     6.1       
pyobjc-framework-FinderSync            6.1       
pyobjc-framework-FSEvents              6.1       
pyobjc-framework-GameCenter            6.1       
pyobjc-framework-GameController        6.1       
pyobjc-framework-GameKit               6.1       
pyobjc-framework-ImageCaptureCore      6.1       
pyobjc-framework-IMServicePlugIn       6.1       
pyobjc-framework-InputMethodKit        6.1       
pyobjc-framework-InstallerPlugins      6.1       
pyobjc-framework-InstantMessage        6.1       
pyobjc-framework-IOSurface             6.1       
pyobjc-framework-iTunesLibrary         6.1       
pyobjc-framework-LatentSemanticMapping 6.1       
pyobjc-framework-LaunchServices        6.1       
pyobjc-framework-libdispatch           6.1       
pyobjc-framework-LocalAuthentication   6.1       
pyobjc-framework-MapKit                6.1       
pyobjc-framework-MediaAccessibility    6.1       
pyobjc-framework-MediaLibrary          6.1       
pyobjc-framework-MediaToolbox          6.1       
pyobjc-framework-MultipeerConnectivity 6.1       
pyobjc-framework-NetFS                 6.1       
pyobjc-framework-NotificationCenter    6.1       
pyobjc-framework-OpenDirectory         6.1       
pyobjc-framework-OSAKit                6.1       
pyobjc-framework-PreferencePanes       6.1       
pyobjc-framework-PubSub                6.1       
pyobjc-framework-QTKit                 6.1       
pyobjc-framework-Quartz                6.1       
pyobjc-framework-SceneKit              6.1       
pyobjc-framework-ScreenSaver           6.1       
pyobjc-framework-ScriptingBridge       6.1       
pyobjc-framework-SearchKit             6.1       
pyobjc-framework-Security              6.1       
pyobjc-framework-SecurityFoundation    6.1       
pyobjc-framework-SecurityInterface     6.1       
pyobjc-framework-ServiceManagement     6.1       
pyobjc-framework-Social                6.1       
pyobjc-framework-SpriteKit             6.1       
pyobjc-framework-StoreKit              6.1       
pyobjc-framework-SyncServices          6.1       
pyobjc-framework-SystemConfiguration   6.1       
pyobjc-framework-VideoToolbox          6.1       
pyobjc-framework-WebKit                6.1       
pyodbc                                 4.0.26    
pyOpenSSL                              19.0.0    
pyparsing                              2.4.0     
pyperclip                              1.7.0     
PyRect                                 0.1.4     
pyrsistent                             0.14.11   
PyScreeze                              0.1.25    
PySocks                                1.7.0     
pytest                                 5.0.1     
pytest-arraydiff                       0.3       
pytest-astropy                         0.5.0     
pytest-doctestplus                     0.3.0     
pytest-openfiles                       0.3.2     
pytest-remotedata                      0.3.1     
python-dateutil                        2.8.0     
PyTweening                             1.0.3     
pytz                                   2019.1    
PyWavelets                             1.0.3     
PyYAML                                 5.1.1     
pyzmq                                  18.0.0    
QtAwesome                              0.5.7     
qtconsole                              4.5.1     
QtPy                                   1.8.0     
requests                               2.22.0    
rope                                   0.14.0    
ruamel-yaml                            0.15.46   
scikit-image                           0.15.0    
scikit-learn                           0.21.2    
scipy                                  1.3.0     
seaborn                                0.9.0     
Send2Trash                             1.5.0     
setuptools                             41.0.1    
simplegeneric                          0.8.1     
singledispatch                         3.4.0.3   
six                                    1.12.0    
sklearn                                0.0       
snowballstemmer                        1.9.0     
sortedcollections                      1.1.2     
sortedcontainers                       2.1.0     
soupsieve                              1.8       
Sphinx                                 2.1.2     
sphinxcontrib-applehelp                1.0.1     
sphinxcontrib-devhelp                  1.0.1     
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp                 1.0.2     
sphinxcontrib-jsmath                   1.0.1     
sphinxcontrib-qthelp                   1.0.2     
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml          1.1.3     
sphinxcontrib-websupport               1.1.2     
spyder                                 3.3.6     
spyder-kernels                         0.5.1     
SQLAlchemy                             1.3.5     
statsmodels                            0.10.0    
sympy                                  1.4       
tables                                 3.5.2     
tblib                                  1.4.0     
tensorboard                            1.14.0    
tensorflow                             1.14.0    
tensorflow-estimator                   1.14.0    
termcolor                              1.1.0     
terminado                              0.8.2     
testpath                               0.4.2     
tflearn                                0.3.2     
toolz                                  0.10.0    
tornado                                6.0.3     
tqdm                                   4.32.1    
traitlets                              4.3.2     
unicodecsv                             0.14.1    
urllib3                                1.24.2    
wcwidth                                0.1.7     
webencodings                           0.5.1     
Werkzeug                               0.15.4    
wheel                                  0.33.4    
widgetsnbextension                     3.5.0     
wrapt                                  1.11.2    
wurlitzer                              1.0.2     
xlrd                                   1.2.0     
XlsxWriter                             1.1.8     
xlwings                                0.15.8    
xlwt                                   1.3.0     
zict                                   1.0.0     
zipp                                   0.5.1
```

If you look at the O section you see opencv-python, but in my project when I try import it using

```
import cv2
```

it doesn't work and gives me this error message...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .cv2 import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cv2/cv2.cpython-38-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _clock_gettime
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/libavutil.56.31.100.dylib (which was built for Mac OS X 10.12)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/libavutil.56.31.100.dylib
```

I have tried the following ways to import it, but nothing seems to work

```
import opencv
import cv4
import cv3
import cv
import opencv-python
etc...
```

Any help would be greatly appreciate and thank you in advance

Comment: Try installing it using conda.  First, uninstall the pip version: `pip uninstall opencv` (or whichever package name you installed). Then `conda install opencv`.

Comment: Thanks I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

**I believe that you are using masOS.**

This is a bug in the latest Pillow 5.1.0 release.

It was caused by upgrading Xcode from version 8 to 9.2 for building the binary wheels.

El Capitan 10.11 is the "min macOS to run" for Xcode 8.

Sierra 10.12.6 is the min for Xcode 9.2.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode#Xcode_7.0_-9.x(since_Free_On-Device_Development

There will be a Pillow 5.1.1 out to fix it at some point.

In the meantime, the workaround is: pip install 'pillow!=5.1.0'

(Or upgrade your macOS, or build from source.)

For more info, see https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/3068

Comment: Still you are not able to install opencv?

Comment: @JackB226 you are using macOS?

Comment: pip install 'pillow!=5.1.0'
Requirement already satisfied: pillow!=5.1.0 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (6.1.0)
It says this and when I try import cv2 it still has the same error

Comment: You are using macOS?

Comment: Yes. I am using a Mac

Comment: Pillow                                 5.0.0. This is from typing pip list in terminal, but I tried importing cv2 and it still doesn't seem to work

Comment: Are toy trying from any IDE like pycharn anaconda or using core command prompt?

Comment: I am using anaconda spyder

Comment: No for now don't use any software. Try this using normal command prompt first

Comment: I tried using terminal to import cv2 but it also gives an error

Comment: First install the package numpy and opencv from normal command prompt. and open python console in another command prompt and then try importing it

Answer (score 0):

You show a `pip list`, and a stack trace that indicates you're using Python 3.8. Unless something has gone oddly sideways on MacOS, you'll need to use `pip3` (rather than `pip`) to install `opencv-python`. After that

```
import cv2
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently OpenCV 4.1.x doesn't like El Capitan ... Downgrade OpenCV to `3.4.5.20`:

In the desired environment:

```
pip install --force-reinstall opencv-contrib-python==3.4.5.20
```

Else:

```
sudo -H python3 -m pip install --force-reinstall opencv-contrib-python==3.4.5.20
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one version of python installed make sure that pip is downloading to the one you are using.